# no video in video sequence window

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

[image]I've been playing around with blender today, and now suddenly, I'm no lenger able to get a preview window of the sequence editor.

It just shows a black screen.

I have a videotrack so there should(?) be some output.

edit: Suddenly realized there is no audio either.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44720/2843

Answer (score 3):

On the right to the preview window, you have set a proxy size to 50%. But if you don't build a proxy file, the preview can't show you a video.

So either set the **Preview render** to **No proxy, full render**, or with you video strip selected, scroll down the strip properties until you reach **Proxy/Timecode** and make your desired settings. Finally, to build the proxy files, have your strip selected and go to **Strip** -> **Rebuild Proxy and Timecode indices** and you're good to go.