# Preview and rendered video from VSE suddenly shows nothing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I started using Blender couple of weeks ago to edit some of my video clips. Spent quite a while editing this one, and everything worked fine. Video rendered as it should. The whole project consists of a MP4 file with a whole lot of soft cuts. Came back to it a couple days later and now the preview won't show a thing. When I render the scene, it's just a black screen with no sound.

The original file is still working, as well as my other Blender projects. And the weirdest thing is that if I add a new movie clip to the project, the preview works just fine for that clip.

Can anyone guess what might have caused this? I've googled like crazy and haven't found anything helpful.

[image: A screenshot, in case it might help]

Comment: Is the original video file in the same folder on your hard drive? Has it been renamed or otherwise altered?

Comment: @cegaton is right, that is a typical behaviour when your Footage isn't available in its original Path any more.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40164/2843

Comment: Not sure if this info will help anyone, but I recently experienced a similar problem, where only one track would render... was working until I resized my render dimensions, then all grouped tracks disappeared. I found that by leaving *Use Movie Framerate* checked when adding movie clips I ended up with a very strange framerate, even though the clips were supposed to be 30fps. My grouped tracks were all cropped at the group level. 1. Set your render dimensions before adding footage. 2. Set FPS manually, do not *Use Movie Framerate*. 3. Don't edit tracks on the group level if you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Select your tracks and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to disable the **hide** function.

Comment: As you can see from his screenshot the strips are all unmuted, so this shouldn't be a problem in his case. But it might help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the strip and add it freshly back again.
This will ensure it is located properly.

Comment: It's enough to reopen the referenced Files in the Stips Properties so that you don't loose all of your cuts.

Answer (score 0):

As [cegaton](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1853) [pointed out](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/preview-and-rendered-video-from-vse-suddenly-shows-nothing#comment75371_44720) and as I experienced quite often myself: That's the usual behavior when the footage doesn't exist in its original Folder anymore. Maybe you have moved your `.blend`-file or you have saved your footage on a Removable Device or moved it somewhere else.

So try to put your footage and your `.blend`-file back to where it was when you added it into your VSE.

Or you can try to use Blenders **Find Missing Files** function in the *File* menu under *External Data*:

[image: Find Missing Files Screenshot]

There are questions related to this problem which might enlighten your situation a bit ;-)

- [How to replace an orphaned external file by an existing one? (all instances)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40411/how-to-replace-an-orphaned-external-file-by-an-existing-one-all-instances)
- [What can I do to move a file to a new folder and leave its import image as plane intact?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44006/what-can-i-do-to-move-a-file-to-a-new-folder-and-leave-its-import-image-as-plane)
- [Answer to "no video in video sequence window"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27045/2843)
- [Blender only renders black frames](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40164/blender-only-renders-black-frames)

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding a new strip to the end and the running rebuild proxies restored all the others

Comment: Like what do you mean?

Comment: I added a new strip to the file where the strips seemed to have lost their connection to the original files.  I then when to the proxies menu and built a proxy for the new movie file added.  After this all the other files seemed to restore to the original poxy connections - if you are not sure what a proxy file look up the help on proxy building for blender