# Video won't render properly, only audio?

Tags: rendering, video

I recently created a 3:45 minute video, it's like a montage, a lot of short clips put together. It's my first time using blender but everything seemed to go smoothly, except that now that I want to render, the only thing I get is a black screen but the audio is there. If it's any help, whenever I change my proxy from 25% the preview window doesn't show my video anymore. It won't play my video unless I have it set to 25%. This is what I used to edit, since my laptop had an easier time loading the full FPS of the clips with this low proxy. However, whenever I try to make a proxy for 50, 75, or 100%, the progress bar goes maybe to 5% and then disappears. Being a first time user, this is a bad experience as I put so much time into this and now I can't render. Is there any way I can fix this? I'm clueless

Comment: You most likely have once let Blender create the 25% proxy files and then moved your footage or \*.blend-file to a different location afterwards so that Blender can't find it any more...

Comment: Is there any way to fix this? Or I may have deleted the files, they would still be in the recycle bin but what am I looking for? The proxy file for each clip?

Comment: You're looking for the original footage - your clips source video files. There's a menu entry in the File menu helping you find lost files. Or just look at one strip in your VSE and see where it points to and if your source footage is still there or if you can put it back there again. There already are some questions with good answers about this here...

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61537/2843, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45497/2843

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview and rendered video from VSE suddenly shows nothing](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/preview-and-rendered-video-from-vse-suddenly-shows-nothing)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to go through my files and just found that after I had imported a lot of the clips into Blender I had organized my folders. So I moved most of these clips to another location and that was my problem. I just moved them back and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You have once let Blender create the 25% proxy files and then moved your footage or **.blend* file to a different location afterwards so that Blender can't find it any more...

You have to look for the original footage - your clips source video files and put them back in place where they originally were. There's a [menu entry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45497/2843) in the File menu helping you to find lost files. Or just look at one strip in your VSE and see where it points to and if your source footage is still there or if you can put it back there again. There already are some questions with good answers about [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61537/2843) here on BSE...